# Modified broken stick problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics

The following question is taken from Mark Joshi's Quant Job Interview.

> Question: Let $x,y$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and separate the unit interval $[0,1]$ into $3$ pieces. What is the probability of forming a triangle using the $3$ segments if the second point is chosen to break the longer segment left after the first point has been chosen?

This is a modified version of the well-known broken stick problem. The original problem does not have restriction on point to break the longer segment. For that problem, the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$ by merely checking triangle inequality.

However, in this modified question, I have no idea how to start at all.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  if $x\in [0,\frac 12]$ the relevant probability is $1-x$, so first integrate from $0$ to $\frac 12$  Argue that the other case $x\in \mathbb [\frac 12,1]$ must give the same value.

Comment: @lulu I am still a bit lost. Can you elaborate more? Why would the relevant probability is $1-x$ when $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]?$

Comment: Work it for a particular example.  Suppose $x=\frac 13$.  What is the relevant probability in that case?

Comment: "What is the probability .. " of what ?

Comment: @GCab Edited. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Note:  the edit changed the question significantly.  My comments concerned the question "find the probability that the second point breaks the longer segment."  The corrected question can be approached by computing the probability that a point drawn uniformly at random from the longer segment leaves no segment of length $>\frac 12$.

Comment: First you say that $x,y$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Then you say that the second point (presumably $y$) is chosen etc. These are contradictory! Do you mean "What is the probability of forming a triangle using the 3 segments given that $y$ breaks the longer of the two segments $[0,x]$ and $[x,1]$?"?

Comment: Wait! Even that isn't good enough. Perhaps you mean "First $x$ is chosen uniformly in $[0,1]$. Then $y$ is chosen uniformly in $[0,x]$ (if $x\ge\frac12$) or $[x,1]$ (if $x<\frac12$)." That will give you a different answer than the suggestion in my previous comment. Or maybe you don't actually know what you mean? The expression "can of worms" springs to mind.

Comment: Did you copy the problem verbatim from the book? If not, please do so!

Answer (score 3):

Let's go in the geometric way.

[image: Stick_dep_break_1]

*case a) - classic - breakings independent*

The two breaking points ,  $x$ and $y$, are each uniformly and independently distributed on $[0,1]$.
That it is the same as saying that the point $(x,y)$ is uniformly distributed on the unit square $[0,1]^2$.
We can partition the outcomes into two different sets: $0 \le x \le y \le 1$ and the symmetric $0 \le y < x \le 1$ 
("above" and "below" the diagonal).

For a triangle to be formed, each piece shall be smaller that the sum of the others.

In the set "above", the three pieces have lengths $x, y-x, 1-y$.

Therefore we shall have
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x \le y \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  \left( {1 - y < y} \right)\; \wedge \left( {x < 1 - y + y - x} \right)\; \wedge \;\left( {y - x < x + 1 - y} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x \le y \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  \left( {1/2 < y} \right)\; \wedge \left( {x < 1/2} \right)\; \wedge \;\left( {y - x < 1/2} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
and it is easy to see that the conditions define a right triangle (that in yellow in the sketch) with sides $1/2$, and thus  with an area which is $1/4$
of the "above" diagonal triangle, and the two symmetric possible areas total as well $1/4$ of the unit square.

*case b) -present - second break dependent on the first*

The first cutting point $x$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.
Once $x$ has been selected,  $y$
is uniformly chosen on the longer segment, which is either $x$ or $1-x$.
That means that either $x \le 1/2$ and $x \le y$ or $1/2 < x$ and $y < x$.
The possible cases are represented by the unit square, deducting the two shaded triangles.
The positive results remain as above, but now **their ratio is $1/3$**.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Why do we consider the upper part of the diagonal in the present case?

Comment: What do you mean by "the upper part of the diagonal"? Do you mean simply $y\ge x$? The problem is badly stated, so I can't be sure, but I think for instance the point $(0.6,0.7)$ isn't allowed, although $y>x$.

Comment: @Idonknow: really sorry, my previous answer was effectively wrong. I reconsidered more carefully your premises and recasted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_1,L_2,L_3$ denote the length of the $3$ segments.

A triangle *cannot* be made if and only if one of the following conditions is satisfied:

- $L_1+L_2\leq L_3$
- $L_1+L_3\leq L_2$
- $L_2+L_3\leq L_1$

Taking into account that $L_1+L_2+L_3=1$ the conditions can be rewritten as:

- $L_3\geq\frac12$
- $L_2\geq\frac12$
- $L_1\geq\frac12$

So we conclude that a triangle can be made iff $L_i<\frac12$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Projecting this on $x,y$ we find that a triangle can be made iff:

$$\left[x<\frac12\text{ and }\frac12<y<x+\frac12\right]\text{ or }\left[y<\frac12\text{ and }\frac12<x<y+\frac12\right]$$

Denoting this condition as $P(x,y)$ it now remains to find the area of: $$\left\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\mid P(x,y)\right\}$$

I leave that to you.

Comment: So the answer is $\frac{1}{2}?$

Comment: I found $\frac18+\frac18=\frac14$ which is twice the area of $$\left\{(x,y)\in\left[0,\frac12\right)\times\left(\frac12,1\right]\mid y<x+\frac12\right\}$$